# how to get content change event of ul in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

Hi I have a ul and that ul is populated through ajax request. Now I want to trigger a functiont whenever the content is placed or changed in that `ul`. My ul is like this

```
 <ul class="prodListing" id="prodListing"></ul>
```

I have tried `.bind()` function with `contentchange` like this

```
$(".prodListing").bind('contentchange', function() {
                alert("called");
                show_Socialshare();
        });
```

And also tried

```
$(".prodListing").change(function(){
            alert("called");
            show_Socialshare();
});
```

But both are not working. Can any body tell me how can I fire the function on this event

Comment: There isn't a contentchange event other than using DOMMutation Events. I suggest instead using the done or success callback of the ajax request that populates the UL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
$(document).bind('ajaxComplete', function(){
    alert("called");
    show_Socialshare();
});
```

This will watch the document for any ajax calls and run once it's complete.

Answer (score 2):

Contentchange isn't a real event, but if you know the places where your content changes you can trigger  it as a custom event.

```
 $(".prodListing").trigger("contentchange")
```

Update: However handling this in the onsucces of your ajaxrequest is indeed probably what you need.(see other comment)